# C++ call method from the main Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, synchronization

In one of my class i'm launching a thread using the following method:

```
HANDLE hThread;
unsigned threadID;
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &myThread, NULL, 0, &threadID );
```

And from this thread I would like to call a method that has to be called from the main thread (the method is interacting with the UI) but I really don't know how to do it since the main thread can't wait until "myThread" notifies it.

I have seen a lot of

```
while(true){
  //wait something from myThread
}
```

But I can't wait this way!

Any ideas?

Comment: What platform or platforms does this have to run on? Threading in C++ is a very platform dependant thing.

Comment: My plateform is Windows!

Comment: You need `EnterCriticalSection()`.

Comment: I can't see how to use EnterCriticalSection() to solve my problem!

Comment: You can use PostMessage()/PostThreadMessage() to notify your main thread from your created thread while staying in the traditional message loop. Depdning on whether your thread needs a response it can then wait for a response using some other synchronisation object and shared resource or you could use a message loop in your created thread and PostThreadMessage() to get the result back.

Comment: You might consider using the thread functionality in `C++11`, I'll bet there's a solution in there for you.

Comment: @Wug: I think platform is obvious from the ugly Windows-esqe `HANDLE` code.

Comment: Yeah, that and _beginthreadex (A windows API call) gave it away.  Wasn't sure if OP cared about cross-platform-itude or didn't realize that his code won't work on any other platform

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43994/The-Practical-Guide-to-Multithreading-Part-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your main thread is UI, you can send a message to it.

```
#define WM_USER_EXECUTE_MY_CODE (WM_USER + 1000)
```

Your UI message loop should process the message:

```
// API code
// LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
// create message map yourself if you're using MFC

if (iMsg == WM_USER_EXECUTE_MY_CODE)
{
    // execute your code must run in main thread
}
```

And in your worker thread, send UI a message

```
// HWND hwnd = handle to main UI window
// if you need some parameters, send them through WPARAM or LPARAM
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_USER_EXECUTE_MY_CODE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Should be `PostMessage`, otherwise delay by UI thread will delay overall operation.

Comment: @Ajay I think it depends. If he wants to execute some other code after the call, he has to use SendMessage.

Comment: @darkheir Since your main thread is not UI, assume you're using a console app, your main thread must be waiting to execute the code. Either while(1) loop or WaitForSingleObject will do. Simply set a flag or call SetEvent.

Comment: @Rango not the answer i was hoping ^^ I hoped that it was possible to send a message to a non UI thread whitout a waiting loop but it donesn't seem posible!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wait for one or more threads with WaitForMultipleObjects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687055(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But don't wait on the thread itself (which waits for it to exit), wait on an event set by the thread (`CreateEvent`, `SetEvent`).

Comment: Yeah but i can't wait for the thread, my UI still need to be reactive!

Comment: You could just use a small timeout so the UI doesn't become unresponsive.  Other answer is better however.